# Can I decrypt a KMS key from a different account, from a different aws region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-cdk, amazon-kms

Here's my scenario:

- There are two aws accounts - `A` and `B`.
- I have a KMS key `K` protecting an SQS queue in account `A` and region `us-east-1`.
- I have an SNS topic in account `B` and region `us-west-2`.
- My SQS queue from account `A` is subscribed to the topic from account `B`.
- My KMS key's resource policy currently allows the SNS topic to perform encryption/decryption. I am using AWS CDK for my application. Following is the line of code that sets up these permissions:

```
encryptionMasterKey.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ["kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource"],
            resources: ["*"],
            principals: [new iam.AccountPrincipal("<account B id>")]
        }));
```

Now, here are my observations:

- If I leave the SQS queue unencrypted, my SNS topic is able to deliver message to my queue.
- However, if I enable SSE encryption on the queue with KMS key `K`, the SNS topic fails with `KMS.AccessDeniedException`.

I need to be able to encrypt my queue for business reasons. How can I allow my SNS topic to access the KMS key?

Comment: You need add sns as principle to kms.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the AWS account principal, you also need to have a policy that grants the Amazon SNS service principal permission for using the KMS key.

```
{
    "Sid": "Allow access for SNS Service Principal",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": [
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:Decrypt"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

You can also find a more detailed post regarding the [setup here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/).

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through a similar problem, check the question and answer here: [SNS not being able to send messages to SQS queue in another account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73492182/sns-not-being-able-to-send-messages-to-sqs-queue-in-another-account/73710350#73710350)

TL;DR:
In addition to @user3099576 's answer, you need to use a multi-region KMS key that was created in one of the two regions with a replica in the other region. KMS Keys are not cross-region as of now.